# What tools or practices are available in Ruby for massive real time data in the server and its visualization on the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, gps

I have 50 GPS devices that send latitude & longitude information using **HTTP requests.**

I would like to be like to represent this information on the browser in real time.

My doubts are:

1. What tools are available in Ruby for handling massive real time data. It comes as HTTP requests.
2. What tools are available in the browser for displaying real time data?

I am not sure if it is possible for the browser side to use the data coming from the GPS devices directly, without saving it on the DB. Or perhaps I must save it on the DB. I would like some ideas on this regard.

Comment: Is the request huge, or is it the response? It's not clear why either would be huge. By graphical representation do you mean a google map?

Comment: yes any map ..It is huge because it will always send data

Comment: I am not getting how to make it possible. you have any ideas

Comment: you can use google highcharts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be push notifications will help you. one of the implementation with faye gem can be found at  http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Answer (score 0):

1, Faye
Faye is simple and aw gem for push message to web client or else .
But it well waste power.

There is a artical for you :how to bulid faye for you project .
http://blog.csdn.net/hexudong08/article/details/6957574

2, Bustle
https://github.com/fredwu/bustle

3, Juggernaut

4,  xmpp